# Recording audio with Javascript and using it with Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-cognitive-services, mediastream

As the title suggests, I am making a web application in ASP.Net Core MVC that records the audio from the user's computer:

```
function startRecording(btn) {
    var countdown = 5;
    var audioChunks = [];
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    var mediaRecorder = null;
    var options = { mimeType: 'audio/webm' }; //I tried changing it to audio/wav but it doesn't work
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
        mediaRecorder.start();

        setTimeout(function () {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            btn.text("Waiting for the results");
        }, countdown * 1000);

        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function (event) {
            audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", function () {
            var blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('audioBlob', blob);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ProcessAudio", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    // Display the result in the modal
                    $('#modalContent').html(data);

                    // Show the modal
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('Error processing audio');
                }
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error starting recording:', error);
    });
}
```

Then I process and save the audio into a file within the server:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ProcessAudio(IFormFile audioBlob)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Resources", "recording.wav");

    if (audioBlob != null && audioBlob.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = audioBlob.OpenReadStream())
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }

    var model = new AudioReadingModel(filePath);

    model.RecordAndCalculate();
    return PartialView("ShowResults", model);
}
```

However, when I hit the following line in my code:

```
var recognizer = new Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(AudioPath));
```

It gives me the following exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Exception
> with an error code: 0xa (SPXERR_INVALID_HEADER))'

The file has the .wav extension and I can listen to it on my computer so I really need help finding out what is going on. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to recognize the audio file.

```
  var speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey.value, serviceRegion.value);    
  speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
  var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(audioFile);
  recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
```